# AJAX - the request is done correctly but the error function is executed

Tags: jquery, ajax, http

I have an AJAX request from the server that save one user on the database :

**JavaScript**

```
u.first_name = "chaabaoui";
u.last_name = "aymene";
u.mot_de_passe = "123";
u.type = 0;
u.email = "ekka@gmail.com";         
$.ajax({
    url : "http://localhost:8080/utilisateurs/addUser",
    headers: { 
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
    },
    type : "POST",
    data : JSON.stringify(u),
    dataType : "application/json",
    success : function(response) {
                  console.log("the request is done,");
                  if(response == "true") {
                      console.log("and the user was saved");
                  } else {
                      console.log("but the user was not saved");
                  }
              },
    error : function(error) {
                console.log("the request was failed ", error);
            },
    complete : function(xhr , status) {
                   console.log("the requeste is complete");
               }
});
```

The problem user is saved to database but error message from the error function is displayed ("the request was failed") instead of the success message. I need to know what is wrong here. Most importantly, why the success message is not executed?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How does the response look like and what status code is returned?

Comment: Check the Network tab in devtools to see the response to the request.

Comment: `dataType : "application/json",` is not valid. If the server returns JSON, it should be `dataType: "json"`

Comment: You don't need `'Accept': 'application/json',` in the headers, that's done automatically when you use `dataType: "json"`.

Comment: thank you @NielsNet , the status code is 200

Comment: i think the problem is from _datatype : "application/json"_ now all is good.

Answer (score 0):

Seing your console should be enougth to see the error, because you have:

```
 error : function(error){
             console.log("the request was failed ", error);
         },
```

but if its not showing nothing, just check your request on Network Tab(developer tools) using chrome(or another browser), it should be at least and error request with the response message

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference